# how to change default language of SQL server management studio 2008R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I tried to change default language to french by using the below query.

```
USE ssidps;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 2 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
```

but `SELECT @@language` gives "us_english" always.

My aim is to change my onshore system's default language from korean to english. All error/warning messages are coming in korean when query failed. And i couldn't catch that message as i developed in English.

Its working in the current session by the query "set language french" but not for the database.
I asked the same in stackexchange but i was referred to this site.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654101/how-to-change-default-language-of-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: Please don't cross-post.

Answer (score 3):

**Using SSMS :**

To do so, open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) > Right click Server in Object Explorer > Properties > Advanced > Check the ‘Default Language’ property and make sure it is set to the one you want.

[image]

**using TSQL:**

Look up the sys.messages catalog view to check if SQL Server supports a message in your local language.

```
SELECT msg.language_id, lang.langid, alias 
FROM
sys.messages AS msg
JOIN
syslanguages AS lang
ON lang.msglangid = msg.language_id
GROUP BY  msg.language_id, lang.langid, alias
```

then once you know the `langid` use below tsql

```
EXEC sp_configure "default language", n  -- n = `langid` that you want to set
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
```

note: you have to restart SQL server and  this is an **instance wide** setting.

Comment: I have tried these before. Any way i have re-install SQL server 2008R2 with certain language.

Comment: +1 for giving the TSQL source. Changing from the UI was disabled for some reason.